# How to not let my image move out of scene

Tags: image, javafx, scene

Here is my following code:

```
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500, Color.RED);

    ImageView dice = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("dice.jpeg")));
    dice.setX(0);
    dice.setY(300);
    root.getChildren().add(dice);

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (dice.getX() >= 0 &&  dice.getX() <= 500 ) {
            switch (e.getCode()) {

                case RIGHT:
                    dice.setX(dice.getX() + KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                    break;

                case LEFT:
                    dice.setX(dice.getX() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                    break;
             }
           }
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

In my code, my image `dice` can move left and right, but I don't want it to go outside the scene. I want it to not move once it reaches to end of the scene in both left and right. I tried doing it with `if` statement, but it doesn't work. Is there any way I can stop my image `dice`to not move out of scene? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where you have the x.pos() < 500 and that testing you made need to add the width of x to the left side of the inequality

Comment: @BenWebb Can you please show me how to do that? I didn't get

Comment: I am not exactly sure on the code base of JavaScript but it would be something like dice.getX() + dice.width() / 2 >= 500. This is because dice.getX() does not return the point on the image closest to the border. I am not sure on the exact direction of the inequalities (>) and order of operations so you will have to try switching the sides of the expressions. This should find the answer you are looking for

Comment: @BenWebb I tried doing it, but it's not working.

Comment: Should you use `minX` and `maxX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your answer. Firstly, the way you check the boundaries. If the condition is met, your keys no longer control the `ImageView`. Secondly, using `dice.getX()` in your test condition. It's best if you use `dice.getLayoutBounds().getMaxX()` and `dice.getLayoutBounds().getMinX()`. Also, I recommend using `scene.getWidth()` instead of hard coding the width of the `Scene`, because the `Scene` width can be changed. <-(in your posted code).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFxTestingGround extends Application {

    double KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA = 5;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500, Color.RED);

        ImageView dice = new ImageView(createImage("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/250163910454280192/296377451599364107/Untitled.png"));
        dice.setFitHeight(100);
        dice.setFitWidth(100);
        dice.setX(0);
        dice.setY(300);
        root.getChildren().add(dice);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {       
            System.out.println(dice.getLayoutBounds().getMinX() + " : " + dice.getLayoutBounds().getMaxX() + " : " + scene.getWidth());
            switch (e.getCode()) {
                case RIGHT:
                    dice.setX(dice.getX() + KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                    break;

                case LEFT:
                    dice.setX(dice.getX() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                    break;
             }


            if (dice.getLayoutBounds().getMinX() < 0)   
            {
                dice.setX(0);
            }            
            else if(dice.getLayoutBounds().getMaxX() > scene.getWidth() )
            {
                dice.setX(dice.getX() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
            }           
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    Image createImage(String url)
    throws IOException {
        URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)");

        try (InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream()) {
            return new Image(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's that code in the bottom? `Image createImage(String url)
    throws IOException {
        URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)");

        try (InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream()) {
            return new Image(stream);
        }`

Comment: I used an image hosted online. That code helps the image load. You don not need that. I just wanted this answer to work right out the box. Your code is good, except inside the handler.